# Can we manage the deployment of each django app within a single Django project independently?

Tags: python, django, django-apps, django-deployment

Lets say we have one django project that has two apps - FooApp & BarApp.

Each app talks to its own database. Meaning they both manage their own set of models. Is it possible to manage the deployments of these apps independently? It's okay for them to be deployed on same server within the same nginx process as long as I am able to make changes to the apps without bringing down the other as well.

I understand that these can very well be separate projects and they can communicate with each other using RESTful APIs. For my needs, I want to avoid that REST interaction for the time being.

The django documentation [here][1] describes a django project and django app as follows

Django project:

> The term project describes a Django web application.

Django App:

> The term application describes a Python package that provides some set
> of features.

So if the app is simply a python package, and the django project is really the one that defines how these apps are managed via the settings module, then I suppose there is no straight forward way of accomplishing what I want. Or is there anything I can do?

TIA
[1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/